# can i say "NO" to "Clone multiply-claimed blocks" in fsck?

Tags: linux, ext3, disaster-recovery, fsck

I need to know if i can still mount the volume  when i tell fsck "no" in that question.

i dont need to repair all the files in the volume, i just need recover one single file for this event. 
the volume got some big files that put fsck stuck for hours if i say "Yes".
    has 753108 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 3 file(s):

The volume if over LVM and runs a EXT3 Filesistem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Huge amounts of "multiply-claimed blocks" during fsck](http://serverfault.com/questions/366863/huge-amounts-of-multiply-claimed-blocks-during-fsck)

Answer (score 1):

Don't repair it. Mount it read only and get your file. When you're done, wipe the drive.

Since you have a superblock error, you can try to mount the filesystem using an alternate superblock. See

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/

(if someone could edit in the instructions I would appreciate it. I'm on a phone.)

Comment: it told me the there was no superblock

Comment: the damage was done with a buggy hybrid sata raid controller

Comment: See my edit. You can mount read only using an alternate superblock.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount the filesystem even though it has multiply-claimed blocks.  Do this on an image (I assume you're already working from a bitwise image of the partition, but it never hurts to check).

Multiply claimed blocks will cause corruption for sure if you try to write to them, but you should be able to read from the file you want if this is the only problem (and hopefully fsck can make that so).